# mod_rewrite strange infinite recursions

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Server is Apache 2.4.18, PHP ver 7.0...

Intro:
On php side I rawurlencode($name) when creating html link.

REQUEST_URI looks like this:

```
/lang/cat1/cat2/product with bla (this/that)    -- works
/lang/cat1/cat2/product with bla (this/ that)   -- infinite internal redirect
```

The difference is only in one space **this/ that** vs. **this/that**

```
VirtualHost:
# I have tried different combinations of
AllowEncodedSlashes On
AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode.

htaccess:
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews     #different combinations
RewriteEngine On


# tried different combinations
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?file\.php$
#RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
#RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200
RewriteRule .? file.php [L] # END
</IfModule>
```

All I want is standard front controller, ALL requests should go to file.php That works in 99.99% of cases. But ruri with `bla/` in it goes to infinite recursions.

Questions:
Why is this happening?
How to solve it?

Comment: [Enable logging](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging) at `trace8` levels if you can, then check your error logs to see what's actually happening.

Comment: DId that. Log was full of "recursions"

Answer (score 0):

You need to uncomment your last rewrite condition.

Try :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews     #different combinations
RewriteEngine On


# tried different combinations
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?file\.php$
#RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200


# END
</IfModule>
```

Otherwise your rule will redirect **/file.php** to itself.

On apache 2.4 you can simply use END flag to terminate the rewrite processing :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule .? file.php [END]
```

Comment: Thanks for a try. But I have tried ALL combinations of commenting and uncomenting !

Comment: Do you have any other rules?

Comment: Yes, I had many. Then I deleted them ALL! I have left only code I have shown here. And yes, I have tried almost all combinations of [END] [END,L] [L,END], [NE], .... :(  This worked ok on Apache 2.2...

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution on another forum.
Solution was painfully simple. But might help someone.

One guy sad: `Be brave, understand that there is nothing wrong with your htaccess! But you still have recursions. So bug is somewhere in php code.`

That destroyed my htaccess fixation allowing me to dive into business and fw code. Bug was found few hours later. One of url functions had premature rawurldecode(). Cool for lazy programin, not so cool if you have products with encoded / in names.

But the answer to question "Did this work before?" was misleading also. "Yes, sure. It must be because of resent migration."
Riiight ;)

Comment: You should still eliminate sources of recursion. Your main rule should be something like `RewriteRule ^(?!file\.php(?:$|/)) file.php [NS,END]` to prevent matching already rewritten URLs.

Comment: Yes, original rewrite rule was completely ok. Terminated last rule with L or END works fine. Bug was in premature decoded url string! That disrupt whole logic, forcing fw to redirect to "correct" url which was premature decoded which lead to redirect to "correct" url ans so on.

Comment: No, not ok, just working. Recursion is still occurring at the rewrite stage. If Apache didn't have a limit (to stop rules like that breaking servers) your rule would never serve a file. Your'e wasting processing on every request. If you'd had a better rule to begin with, your logs would have been clearer.

Comment: @Walf I don't understand, please explain what is wrong with `RewriteRule .? file.php [L]`

Comment: It matches itself on [subsequent passes](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/tech.html#InternalRuleset).

Comment: So, you'll put [END] instead of [L]?

Comment: Read my first comment again, and then RTFM.

Comment: To what recursion are you referring? There is no more infinite recursion! This is just a simple FrontController pattern. htaccess was ok. The bug was in PHP code that is fixed. 1. file.php can not be rewriten because `initial URL equal rewritten URL ... [IGNORING REWRITE]`  2. no one will ever request for file.php. Even if they bruteforce it's real name rule 1 still applies. URI changed? -> No -> serve resource. Logs are fine. Just one pass per request. even if request is file.php

Comment: I didn't say infinite, I said finite. That message is Apache preventing recursion because you don't know how, and you're ignoring advice to make it better.

Comment: I see what you mean. There was one more pass for `.?`. If `^(?!file\.php(?:$|/))` is same as `!^file.php` there will be few less lines in log